# Is there a way to see all running coroutines (Jobs) in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I know there is a Threads window under Debug tab, but is there a way to graphically see outstanding Jobs?

Comment: Can you define a "Job" - is this a kotlin coroutine library or a java core class?

Comment: The job as used by launch/await

Answer (score 2):

kotlin 1.4 adds a debugger with a coroutines tab.
https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-rc-debugging-coroutines/