# Does IntelliJ provide someway to check if two methods are really called in parallel when used kotlinx.coroutines.async

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to call at same time (parallelism) two diferent endpoints. For reach that I decide to use coroutineScope and async. Here is the basic implementation:

```
suspend private fun myMethod(): List<Any> {
    return runBlocking {
        listOf(
            async { method1() },
            async { method2() }
        ).map { it.await() }
    }
}
```

Method1 and method2 are simple request to diferent endpoints. Method1 can be called in the same time as method2 because they are completly independent.

How can I check in IntelliJ if they are really been called at same time?

The closest answer I found was https://stackoverflow.com/a/63219225/4148175 and I read https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-rc-debugging-coroutines/ but I couldn't find someway to check if method1 and method2 are realy executed in parallel.

Comment: Just a side note: I don't think `runBlocking` should be used inside a coroutine. the block (as in block of code) should be `coroutineScope`, because as the name implies, it will otherwise block the thread, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder

Comment: @thinkgruen, thanks. It is my first time coding with coroutines. My main purpose is just call two diferent endponts at same time (in parallel). Kindly, how would you reach that? The code above compiled and run but as far as I can see using second tool for traces (Jaeger) it is calling the endpoints sequentially instead of parallel.

Comment: I think what you could try is to use `awaitAll` instead of `listOf` & `map`. This looks like a sequential call to me, so you first await element1, then await element2.

Comment: @thinkgruen, thank you so much! In fact the reason I wrote this question is exactly because I have noted it has been executed sequentially instead of parallelly. Please, I am quite limited in Kotlin. Can you provide an answer how you would code using awaitAll?

Comment: Sure, you should be able to replace the `map(...)` with `awaitAll()`. After reading a bit more on it, I don't think that this is the cause anymore, but it's a nice method to know nonetheless. In my timezone it's way past bed time, but I hope there will be a solution tomorrow.

Comment: I think in the end the problem might lay in the methods that are being called. It could be that they block the thread without any chance of suspending. If you don't expect a value to be returned, you can also use `launch` instead of `async`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why do you need to verify this? For testing purposes only or do you have any business logic case for that?

Comment: @qwwdfsad it is only for testing purpose. I just figured out that the methods were been executed sequentially after I deployed it to our server (AWS) and looked to our tracebility tool (Jaeger). I need to test locally if they are running in parallel and I am wondering if there is some view or resource in IntelliJ to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the execution time of each one and compare the results. The total time should be approximately equal to the longest execution time of all the functions if they ran in parallel, for example.

```
suspend fun firstFun() {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        delay(1000)
    }
    println("firstFun completed in $time ms.")
}

suspend fun secondFun() {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        delay(1500)
    }
    println("secondFun completed in $time ms.")
}

fun thirdFun() = runBlocking {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        listOf(
            async { firstFun() },
            async { secondFun() }
        ).awaitAll()

    }
    println("thirdFun completed in $time ms.")
}
```

Executing thirdFun() gives something like this:

```
firstFun completed in 1001 ms.
secondFun completed in 1500 ms.
thirdFun completed in 1577 ms.
```

The total time is 1577 ms which is approximately max(fistFun, secondFun), meaning that those two functions actually ran in parallel.